# Atata - Having difficulty prioritizing Tests in Atata framework

Tags: atata

I am new to Atata framework.  We are using Visual Studio (C#) for our Selenium Automation.  I need help with prioritizing my tests. I have multiple tests in my test class.  I want to run this in specific order.

Comment: Any code that you have started to automate testing?

Answer (score 0):

Atata framework is not about test engines and tests ordering. I guess that together with Atata you use one of the testing frameworks: NUnit, xUnit or MSTest. It's their responsibility to execute tests, order, etc. For example, NUnit has [Order Attribute](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Order-Attribute) for tests prioritizing.